# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>` arrow-body-style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const loadUsers = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}`)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        dispatch(getUsers(resp.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
};
```

I'm getting this error in the above code.

Comment: Your current code is working as it is. Please provide the full error stacktrace and a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an arrow function's block only has one return statement, you can omit the block and the `return` keyword. According to the linter you're using, you need to indeed do that:

```js
const loadUsers = () => function (dispatch) {
  axios
    .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}`)
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
      dispatch(getUsers(resp.data));
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

Comment: Yeah its working but gets another error

Comment: Line 10:3:  Expected no linebreak before this expression  implicit-arrow-linebreak

Comment: @Omkar Apparently the `function` can't be on a new line. Edited and fixed.